# Fubini's Theorem: slices of measurable functions not necessarily measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I'm going through Folland's textbook on real analysis, as well as Stein and Shakarchi's. In the latter, they say that if $f(x,y)$ is assumed to be a measurable function on $\mathbb{R}^{d} = \mathbb{R}^{d_{1}} + \mathbb{R}^{d_{2}}$, then it is not necessarily true that the slice $f^{y}(x)$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}^{d_{1}}$ for each $y$.

In Folland, however, he writes that given measure spaces $(X,M, \mu)$ and $(Y, N, \nu)$,
if $f$ is $(M \otimes N)$-measurable, then $f^{y}$ is $M$-measurable for all $y \in Y$. Here, $M \otimes N$ refers to the product $\sigma$-algebra.

Is it not the case that these assertions contradict each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stein and Shakarchi speak of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{L}^d$ of Lebesgue-measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$. This is not the product of the $\sigma$ algebras $\mathcal{L}^{d_1}$ and $\mathcal{L}^{d_2}$ (if $d_k > 0$ for $k\in \{1,2\}$), but the completion (with respect to the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure) of $\mathcal{L}^{d_1}\otimes \mathcal{L}^{d_2}$. That is the difference, there are more $\mathcal{L}^d$-measurable functions than $\mathcal{L}^{d_1}\otimes \mathcal{L}^{d_2}$-measurable. Every slice of an $\mathcal{L}^{d_1}\otimes \mathcal{L}^{d_2}$-measurable function is $\mathcal{L}^{d_k}$-measurable, but not every slice of a $\mathcal{L}^d$-measurable function. For example, the product of a non-measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^{d_1}$ and a null set in $\mathbb{R}^{d_2}$ is Lebesgue-measurable (a null set), but not $\mathcal{L}^{d_1}\otimes \mathcal{L}^{d_2}$-measurable, and its characteristic function is an example of the phenomenon.